# Is there a way to move a split page to a new tab in Vim?

Tags: vim, gvim

I have opened a file in a horizontal or vertical split and which to put it in a new tab instead. Can this be done easily?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Very easily, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

See [the help page](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#CTRL-W_T):

```
:help CTRL-W_T
```

Note that this is case sensitive: `<C-W>T` is different to `<C-W>t`.

Comment: Is it possible to do the reverse of this (move a tab to a split)?

Answer (score 4):

The long-and-straight-forward way would be to open a new tab and open the file's buffer there.

```
:tabnew
:b FILE_NAME
```

`:b` can `TAB`-complete from arbitrary parts of the file name, so this shouldn't take too long.

Answer (score 2):

## Canonical Solution

Suppose there are two buffers:

```
:ls
  1 #h   "match_this_partially.md"  line 1
  2 %a   "food/tacos.txt"           line 1
```

You currently have `food/tacos.txt` open. You want to open `match_this_partially.md` in a new tab.

Simply use the following:

```
:tab sb partial
```

*-- or --*

```
:tab sb 1
```

You can also use wildmenu tab completion in place of `partial`.

---

long form:

- `:tab sbuffer {buffer}`

help:

- `:help :tag`
- `:help :sbuffer`

---

## Alternative Keyboard Solution

Open file in a new split open it in a new tab with the following:

```
<c-w>T
```

#### Use case

*Note: for me `]b` simply is mapped with `nnoremap <silent> ]b :silent execute v:count.'bnext'<cr>`*

If I have few buffers I might do something like this:

1. `<c-w>v` -- create a new vertical split
2. `]b` -- navigate to next buffer (essentially with `:bnext`)
3. `<c-w>T` -- open split in new tab (this destroys the split in the first tab)